# PHP and MySQL - Error querying database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the book "O'Reilly Head First PHP & MySQL" to learn PHP.
Today I wrote this code:

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx','aliendatabase')
  or die('Error conecting to the database');

$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) VALUES ('Sally', 'Jones', '3 days ago', '1 day', 'four', 'green', 'we just talked', 'yes', 'I have seen him', ' sally@gregs-list.net')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) 
    or die ('Error querying database');

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

The connection to the database works fine, I have tested it. But when I run the code I'm getting this error:

```
Error querying database
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: use `mysqli_error($db)` to see what the error is

Comment: you have a blank in a column Name: `how many` think you mean `how_many`

Comment: Blank in: **how many**

Comment: space between `how many` create problem

Comment: how many was the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If that's the [book from 2008](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006303.do) it's way past it's best-due date. Modern PHP would encourage the use of an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) to provide some abstraction here, if not a full [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a great example of how clean and orderly PHP can be if you pick a framework with [a robust database layer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) that makes this super easy.

Comment: replace "how many " to how_many(column name in your database )

Comment: @tadman so you say that I shoudn't learn php from that book? do you have any other ones to recommend? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not that book, no, it's out of date and will only teach you bad habits. While you'll need a good PHP reference, [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/) is actually pretty good. Pick a framework, and then you'll find there's a bunch of material available on that particular subject. Each of them have a different approach to problem solving, so there's no one right answer here.

Comment: @tadman thanks a lot. I aready picked a framework, it's Laravel. But I wanted to have good PHP knowlege before I start with it.

Comment: Good PHP knowledge is always great to have, but start at the top and work down. For example, Eloquent allows [executing arbitrary raw SQL](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) which is useful for building an understanding of how this works.